# PE - Бинарный формат

Tags: exe

Здравствуйте, не могли бы вы подкинуть статей на русском языке о структуре данных в бинарнике pe формата.Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я в свое время читал вот [эту](http://www.wasm.ru/series.php?sid=4) серию статей. Довольно доходчиво все описано.

Answer (score 0):

дока: [pe_coff](http://www.rsdn.ru/article/baseserv/pe_coff.xml) и соответственно инструмент для практики [fasm](http://flatassembler.net/fasmw17003.zip), хотя можно с помощью того-же Си практиковаться.